# Autofac - initialise object with constructor parameters from current class, different class from where builder is

Tags: c#, autofac

In the following code, reduced for clarity, using config and monitor in the second class is straightforward.  How should the timer be created/registered/resolved?  It seems it can't be done in the first class because it requires as constructor parameters values from the second class, but if I understand correctly then all registers/resolves should take place in the first class.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;

using Autofac;

namespace MyServiceApp
{
    static class MyServiceAppMain
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var container = InitContainer())
            {
                    container.Resolve<MyService>().Start();
            }
        }

        private static IContainer InitContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Configuration>().As<IConfiguration>();
            builder.RegisterType<ServicesMonitor>();
            builder.RegisterType<MyService>();

            IContainer container = 
                builder.Build(Autofac.Builder.ContainerBuildOptions.None);

            return container;
        }
    }

    public partial class MyService : ServiceBase, IMyService
    {
        private Timer _processTimer;
        private int _intervalSize;
        private IConfiguration _config;
        private ServicesMonitor _monitor;

        public MyService(IConfiguration config, ServicesMonitor monitor)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _config = config;
            _monitor = monitor;

            _config.ReadAppConfig();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _intervalSize = _config.IntervalMinutes * (60 * 1000);

            _processTimer = 
                new Timer(ProcessTimer_Elapsed, null, Timeout.Infinite, _intervalSize);
        }

        private void ProcessTimer_Elapsed(object sender)
        {
                _processTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, _intervalSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your goal here is testability or otherwise some way to abstract out the creation of the `Timer` object. Since `Timer` doesn't actually implement an interface, you have a few options.

However, **your situation is complicated by the fact you're modifying the `Timer` inside the callback**. From the example, it doesn't look like you're actually making any changes - you set up the original timer with a specific due time and callback period... and then setting it to the same thing later.

**Option One: Do What You're Already Doing**

Inversion of Control is great where it makes sense, but you can't really "fake" a timer or "swap in" a timer for some other implementation. As mentioned, it doesn't implement any `ITimer` interface or something like that.

If you don't have to swap it out... just let it happen. Swap out the config values and stuff during testing to make it more amenable to your tests and call it good.

**Option Two: Wrap the Timer**

If you need to create it outside your class, you'll need to wrap it in... something. Then you can swap out that wrapper.

And since you're modifying the `Timer` itself, you'll need to wrap a little of that functionality in.

```
public class SelfAdjustingTimer
{
  public Timer Timer { get; protected set; }
  public int Interval { get; private set; }
  public SelfAdjustingTimer(int interval)
  {
    this.Interval = interval;
    this.Timer = new Timer(Callback, null, Timeout.Infinite, interval);
  }
  private void Callback(object sender)
  {
    this.Timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, this.Interval);
  }
}
```

You could even add an event or something that gets raised during the callback if you need to know when it happens or do some work based on that.

**Option Three: Crazy Lambda Handler**

It can get really complex, but you know how you can make an event handler with a lambda expression, like...

```
someObj.TheEvent += (sender, args) => { /* Do Work */ };
```

You hypothetically could figure out a way to build a dynamic self-referencing callback using lambda expressions and create the timer callback that way. I've done something like this before and... it gets a little confusing. It's like lambdas that generate lambdas and it takes a while to figure out (which is why I'm not handing it to you here).

**If You Don't Have to Modify The Timer in the Callback**

...then you have more options. You could...

- Create an `ITimerFactory` and have that generate timers for you based on config. Inject that into your class and use it. (`ITimerFactory` and its implementation are things you'd have to create. They don't exist.`)
- Create a `TimerBase` and a `TimerWrapper` the way they did in ASP.NET with `HttpContextBase` and `HttpContextWrapper`. Inject `TimerBase` into your class instead of newing up a `Timer`. For the DI registration for `TimerBase`, that's where you'd look up the config values and set up the real `Timer`.

...and so on. All of the options involve abstracting out the notion of the concrete `Timer` object because, again, it doesn't implement any interface and isn't something you can even derive from.

**If it was me**... I'd probably just do what you're doing, isolate that code as much as possible into a smaller service class that does all the interaction with `Timer` and has nicer methods that are mockable (e.g., wrap `Timer` with something) and then test as much as possible with the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, Travis.  Your comment _"If you don't have to swap it out... just let it happen."_ has set me straight - I'd lost sight of the wood for the trees.  I expect there may still come a time when I face the issue of needing to pass parameters to a constructor (without callbacks - the timer was an obfuscating example), but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.